# How to determine table row causing duplicate entry error in INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, error-handling, foreign-key-relationship

*As I get a lot of answers trying to help me with getting around the error:
I am mostly interested in a **way to do error handling and to detect the table row creating an error** than getting around my actual problem which I only use to illustrate what is coded in the stored procedure.*

---

I am doing an SQL Insert statement in a stored procedure for entries missing in the table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.t1
                      (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
    SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
    FROM         dbo.t2
    WHERE     (NOT EXISTS
                          (SELECT     col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
                            FROM      t1 AS Table_1
                            WHERE     (col1 = t2.col1) AND 
                                      (col2 = t2.col2) AND
                                      (col3 = t2.col3) AND
                                      (col4 = t2.col4) AND
                                      (col5 = t2.col5))) AND
                                       col2 = 'VALUE'
```

t1.col1 + t1.col2 and t1.col3 + t1.col4 have a foreign key relation to another table t3.col1 + t3.col2

The stored procedure fails to finish throwing an error message that the foreign key relation has been violated; i.e. there are some entries missing in t3:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0 [...] INSERT statement is in conflict with
>   FOREIGN-KEY [..]

**What I would like to know is the TABLE ROW of t2 causing the error**, optimally the values in this row. I googled quite a lot about SQL error handling, but only found examples providing the coding line raising the error - which is useless information for me...

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, it seams like you are trying to insert a value in the column with the FK constraint that is not found in the primary key column of the referenced table.

From the query you posted, you are trying to insert all values from `dbo.t2` that doesn't exist in the first table. Then you can use [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operator to insert only the values of `col1, col2, col3, col4, col5` that found in the `dbo.t2` that doesn't present in `dbo.t1` something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.t1
                  (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
    FROM         dbo.t2
    EXCEPT 
    col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
    FROM         dbo.t1
)
```

This way you will guarantee that only the rows that doesn't present in `dbo.t1` get inserted.

If you want to get the data that cause the duplicate entry you can use the `INTERSECT` to get them.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, thanks for suggesting the EXCEPT solution. Still, I do not want to know how I stop my query to throw an error, but I want to know which table row (of T2) is creating the error. I would like to catch the error in the stored routine and then create an output telling me the row where it stopped.

Comment: @WolfiG, aha, I don't think that this possible. Because the insert will be rolled back automatically if something goes wrong. You can edit your question and explain that in more details in order to other users could help you in this.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.t1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM dbo.t2 left join dbo.t1
on t2.col1=t1.col1 and
   t2.col2=t1.col2 and
   t2.col3=t1.col3 and
   t2.col4=t1.col4 and
   t2.col5=t1.col5 
where t1.col1 is null and t1.col2 is null and t1.col3 is null and t1.col4 is null and t1.col5 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, that in `t2` you have rows with values which are not exists in `t3`. (That's why the reference is violated.)

Make sure that `t2` has only the values which are exists in `t3`.

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for your comment. Still, I do not want to know how I stop my query to throw an error, but I want to know which table row (of T2) is creating the error. I would like to catch the error in the stored routine and then create an output telling me the row where it stopped. This is how I want to find out which entries are missing in t3.

Comment: @WolfiG : I think better to write a simple join like this:
SELECT * FROM t2 LEFT join T3 ON t2.col1 = t3.col1 AND t2.col2 = t3.col2 WHERE t3.col1 IS NULL
Whit this you can find out those records. Else you face with a bit difficult problem with errorhandling, but it is also possible with TRY-CATCH

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **INNER JOINs** on your data to remove violating rows.

Comment: Hi Kapil, same like to the other helpful colleagues: It is not so important for me to get around the error. I would like to know how I find rows causeing errors in such situations. I am more interested in this from an interlectual point of view...

Answer (score 0):

Try this using **NOT IN**

```
  INSERT INTO TABLE_2  
 (id, name) SELECT t1.id,  t1.name   
  FROM TABLE_1 t1  WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id                        FROM TABLE_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM Table2 T2
LEFT JOIN  Table1 T1 ON T1.col1 = T2.column1 and T1.col2 = T2.column2 and T1.col3=T2.column3
WHERE T1.col1 IS NULL and T1.col2 IS NULL and T1.col3 IS NULL
```